# Where's my Sufganiyot hat?

Tags: support, winter-bash-2015

The description for the Sufganiyot hat says "post or vote on Dec 14." I voted on something yesterday (I believe it was in SO meta), but I didn't get the hat. What's up with that?

Comment: Maybe meta doesn't count?

Comment: I don't think meta counts. Reasoning: [The airing of grievances hat](http://winterbash2015.stackexchange.com/the-airing-of-grievances) _specifically_ states on Meta- Most hats are only for the main site, usually, as that's where the team wants to encourage participation. From what I've seen, if meta is involved, the hat will usually specifically mention so.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by *yesterday*? Can you estimate the UTC time on which you voted?

Comment: Voting on MSO didn't count for Sufganiyot, however [voting on MSE did count](http://i.stack.imgur.com/YQNsF.png).

Comment: NO HAT FOR YOU.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quoting myself from [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/245123/115866),

> Most hats are awarded for things you do on the main site, but there are a few that are awarded for performing an action on the site's meta. Their requirement generally includes the words "on meta". You still earn these hats *on the main site*, but you earn them for doing something on its child meta.

Implied here is that unless the hat requirements specifically mention "on meta", actions on child metas do not give you hats.